# Best way to use the values across the pages in Windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

Basically i get some of the values in the Page 1 then i need to use it in the Page 3 and Page 5.

So i store this values by using the following code.

```
if (!PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey(key))
   PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Add(key, value);
else
   PhoneApplicationService.Current.State[key] = value;
```

Then i will retrieve it in the Page 3 and Page 5.

I will use more than 50 - 100 objects to use the above code. So will it lead to memory leak ?...

Or Anyone suggest me to use the variables across the pages [ Page 1 to Page 3 ] without using the above approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try implementing the MVVM pattern and binding all of your pages to a single ViewModel, therefore each page will have access to the same 'state'

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521153(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

is the amount of variable fix?
if it is, perhaps you can create global variable in App.cs and save the value to those global variables and retrieve them after you navigate to those page.